# Component unit test passes in isolation but fails in the full test suite

Tags: ember.js, kendo-ui, ember-cli

I've created a date picker component that utilizes Kendo UI. I want to write a unit test that asserts that the date picker is opened when its input field is focussed. Unfortunately the test I've written passes when run in isolation, but fails when run with other tests. Here's my component:

```
//components/date-input.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  _datePicker: null,

  setupDatePicker: function() {
    var datePicker = this.$().kendoDatePicker();
    this.set('_datePicker', datePicker.data('kendoDatePicker'));
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  destroyDatePicker: function() {
    var datePicker = this.get('_datePicker');
    if (datePicker) {
      datePicker.destroy();
    }
    this.set('_datePicker', null);
  }.on('willDestroyElement'),

  openDatePicker: function() {
    this.get('_datePicker').open();
  }.on('focusIn')
});
```

and my unit test:

```
//tests/unit/components/date-input-test.js

import {
  moduleForComponent,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('date-input', 'DateInputComponent');

test('it opens the date picker when focused', function() {
  expect(2);

  this.append();

  equal($('.k-calendar-container').css('display'), 'none',
    'calendar is hidden by default');

  this.subject().$().focus();

  /**** This assertion fails. ****/
  equal($('.k-calendar-container').css('display'), 'block',
    'calendar is displayed after focus');
});
```

The final assertion fails when run with the full test suite with:

```
DateInputComponent: it opens the date picker when focused
    ✘ calendar is displayed after focus
         expected block
         actual none
```

Is there any reason this would pass in isolation but fail when run with the rest of the test suite? I'm using Ember CLI 0.1.12 which uses Ember 1.8.1.

Edit: I've pushed the full source code demonstrating this issue up to https://github.com/pmdarrow/ember-sandbox/tree/kendo-datepicker-test-issue.

Comment: My first debugging thoughts: 1) Whats the output of `equal($('.k-calendar-container').length,1);` 2) What happens when you swap the assertions

Comment: 1) Interestingly, `$('.k-calendar-container').length` is `1` when the test is run in isolation and `2` when two tests are run together. It's like the calendar isn't being destroyed after test runs. Any ideas on how to address this? 2) Swapping the assertions causes the test to fail both in isolation and when run with the rest of the suite.

Comment: It is most likely not being attached to the test container and I'm not sure how patient the test runner is with willDestroyElement.